# Next.js how to set 3 different layouts base on project example

Tags: reactjs, next.js, layout

I use this starter project:

```
https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments
```

The currently default content in above I want to lave original as home.

Now I want add admin and dashboard with different layout.

So I created route:

```
app/dashboard/layout.tsx - I rename this as DashboardLayout
app/dashboard/page.tsx
```

for test I place the same content from:

```
app/layout.tsx
app/page.tsx
```

The problem is now I have duplicated header and footer when I access to page dashboard. So looks like still in layout dashboard also fetch layout from root app layout.tsx

Can anyone help me with this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just want to avoid root layout affet your dashbaord page,

and if that's the case,

I think you can use route group feature of next.js.

(https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups)

All you need to do is placing page and layout in a folder with "()".

```
-- app
--- (layout1)
----- layout.tsx
----- dashboard.tsx
--- (layout2)
----- layout.tsx
----- page.tsx
```

By doing this, you can easily separate layout of the page at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs.

1. If layouts are similiar. I suggest to modify your current navbar and footer for different pages. This will result in less code overall.
2. If Layouts are completelly different your best bet to add navbar and footer to your child layout. And leave main layout without header and footer.
3. If for some reason your header and footer must be in root layout. You can try hiding it on different pages. Although this can be hacky solution. And you might need to implement page loader to avoid double header footer effect.

```
 <html lang="en">
      <body className="bg-black loading">
        <SupabaseProvider>
          <main
            id="skip"
            className="min-h-[calc(100dvh-4rem)] md:min-h[calc(100dvh-5rem)]"
          >
            {children}
          </main>
        </SupabaseProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
const DashboardLayout = (children) => {
  return (
    <div>
     <DashboardNavbar/>
     {children}
     <DashboardFooter/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default DashboardLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

1. If layouts are similar. I suggest you modify your current navbar and footer for different pages. This will result in less code overall.
2. If Layouts are completely different your best bet is to add navbar and footer to your child layout. And leave the main layout without header and footer.
3. If for some reason your header and footer must be in root layout. You can try hiding it on different pages. Although this can be a hacky solution and you might need to implement page loader to avoid double header footer effect.